# Transform 2-dimensional integral to 1-dimensional one

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Simplify $\int_0^1 \int_0 ^x F(x,y)\,dy\,dx$ to a 1-dimensional integral. It is given that $F$ can be written in terms of $F:(x,y)\to f(y)$ with an integrable function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$. 
How does one handle this one?

Comment: there should be some information about F(x,y)

Comment: there is no more information!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: use that
$$\int_0^1\!\!\int_0^x F(x,y)\,dy\,dx = \int_0^1\!\!\int_0^x f(y)\,dy\,dx$$
and apply Fubini:
$$
\int_0^1\!\!\int_0^x f(y)\,dy\,dx =
\int_0^1\!\!\int_y^1 f(y)\,dx\,dy =
\int_0^1(1 - y)f(y)\,dy .
$$

Comment: but so you simply get $\int_0^x f (y) dy$? This does not see correct to me..

Comment: that is a wrong answer

Comment: @shere I applied Fubini and became this. What is wrong?

Comment: @J.D, $\int_0^1\int_0^x\ne\int_0^x\int_0^1$. The interior limits are *variable*,